# Change Line Color of EditText - Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

Can I change the line color on `EditText`. When is active it has some greenish color.[image]

Is it possible to change only the color of line when is active, and how can I do this...?

Comment: it is possible, it is embedded in the background image of the view.

Comment: How can I change it...?

Comment: You can use this site http://android-holo-colors.com/ to create a custom theme for your EditText or other android component

Comment: @Rami Don't rely on tools to do magical stuff for you. Learn how themes are created.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to set background source for an edit text.

1. Generate it http://android-holo-colors.com/
2. Than you can apply generated drawable as background like `android:background="@drawable/my_theme_edit_text"` for the custom `EditText`. Or you can set that background in your app theme - you will find example in .zip file from that site

Comment: Than maybe you should modify .png files to remove that corners. Or just replace them with your own?

Answer (score 10):

add to your **themes.xml** this line:

```
<item name="colorAccent">@color/black</item>
```

this sets the default color for `colorControlActivated` which is used to tint widgets

Answer (score 9):

Here you are:

```
editText.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Answer (score 9):

You can set background of edittext to a rectangle with minus padding on left, right and top to achieve this.

Here is the xml example for setting different line colors for focused and not focused edittext, just set it as background of edittext.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:top="-2dp"
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp">
        <selector >
            <item android:state_enabled="true"
                android:state_focused="true">
                <shape
                    android:shape="rectangle">
                    <stroke
                        android:width="2dp"
                        android:color="#6A9A3A"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:state_enabled="true">
                <shape
                    android:shape="rectangle">
                    <stroke
                        android:width="1dp"
                        android:color="#000000"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </selector>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/text"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textColorHint="#fefefe"
            android:hint="@string/text1"
            android:textColor="#fefefe"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
/>
```

Use the below code in your res/drawable/text.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:top="24.0dp">
   <shape >
      <solid android:color="#fefefe"  />
   </shape>
   </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 5):

you can set android:backgroundTint="@color/blue" to change the color of the Edittext bottom line

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem 
solved it by changing the color of the backgroundTint as follows -

android:backgroundTint="@color/light_color"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `android:background = "@color/black" for the api 21` or above 21 (This will apply for lollypop device or above versions) and for below versions you should use the style to the edittext.

Answer (score 0):

If your using TextInputLayouts for EditText, we should change the following properties.

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">#c5c5c5</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/your color</item>
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/your color</item>
```

By default colour is colorAccent.