# How to change bottom line color of an edit text?

Tags: android, colors, android-edittext

I have a dialog layout in that i have 3 edit texts, for the 1st edit text it shows the underline color as green(primary color), and other two edit text shows the color pink(color accent).

[image]

Why so? It should be same as other two edit texts.

Tried to change this with :

```
 name.getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                name.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

also by the SO solutions. But nothing helped.

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

        ....
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/EditTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="EditTextStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
         <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/border_gray</item>
         <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/border_gray</item>
         <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/border_gray</item>
</style>
```

layout :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Schedule"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_dateTime"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:hint="Date and Time"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edt_name"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/edt_name"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edt_name"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edt_name"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/edt_name"
            android:layout_marginTop="05dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_budget"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:hint="Budget"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edt_dateTime"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edt_dateTime"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/edt_dateTime"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/edt_dateTime"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/edt_dateTime"
            android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
            android:inputType="number" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is what i got after implementing drawable.

[image]

Thank you..

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27151727/3981656

Comment: You can refer my previous [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36003054/5067493) and remove the dashgap or stroke as needed.

Comment: but why dose this happens so? why only for first edit text and for other two? If I dnt wnt to use drawable? @SathishKumarJ

Comment: but why dose this happens so? why only for first edit text and for other two? If I dnt wnt to use drawable? @ShreeKrishna

Comment: @user6265109 just try my answer and tell me about status

Comment: @user6265109 i have just tested it working on my side

Comment: @user6265109 i have tested it on my side working fine

Answer (score 1):

It simply consists of overriding the value for colorControlActivated, colorControlHighlight and colorControlNormal in your app theme definition

```
<style name="Theme.App.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#c5c5c5</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/accent</item>
    </style>
```

or by java

```
editText.getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: I have tried both as stated in question. @user2934536

Answer (score 1):

by changing your "**colorAccent**" color you will change color or edittext bottom line and text input layout as well.

Answer (score 1):

Create `textfield_bg_drawable.xml` in drawable folder. and set it as background resource in `EditText`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <selector>
            <item
                android:state_enabled="true"
                android:state_focused="true">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <stroke
                        android:width="2dp"
                        android:color="@color/focused_line_color" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:state_enabled="true">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <stroke
                        android:width="1dp"
                        android:color="@color/normal_line_color" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </selector>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: What's wrong with this? As I used this drawable I stated the color as accent color, Still it shows me the green color. My accent color is pink. Frustrating :-( @Dhaval Patel

Comment: Have you set drawable `android:background="@drawable/textfield_bg_drawable"` in EditText or in Style?

Comment: Try Clean and Rebuild.

Comment: tried. also did invalid caches ans restart. @Dhaval Patel

Comment: please check the added screen shot in question. For both the edit texts I am using same drawable. Still they are different. @Dhaval Patel

Comment: Are you doing any work on EditText1 programmatically? Check whether  you are applying Color-Filter or not?

Comment: Remove `name.getBackground().mutate().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);` line if it's still present.

Comment: yes i had some code to set it as green. got it. thank you.. @Dhaval Patel

Comment: Glad the solution worked. Would you mind accepting this answer? It might help people experiencing a similar issue and will help getting your question noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this following code properly working on my side

```
        Drawable drawable = editText.getBackground(); // get current EditText drawable
        drawable.setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP); // change the drawable color

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
            editText.setBackground(drawable); // set the new drawable to EditText
        } else {
            editText.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable); // use setBackgroundDrawable because setBackground required API 16
        }
```

Where **editText** is the id of your **EditText**

Comment: @user6265109 actually it is working on my side do you get any error ??

Comment: @user6265109 please have a look with this link http://android--code.blogspot.in/2015/08/android-edittext-bottom-border-color.html

Comment: What's wrong with this? As I used this drawable I stated the color as accent color, Still it shows me the green color. My accent color is pink. Frustrating @Dhiraj

Comment: @user6265109 what output you got when you tried with my code

Comment: it shows the full edit text as green though i have given the color accent i.e. pink. it dose not set the color to bottom line. That's the thing also for the first edit text only it shows the green color, i tried with both edit texts for second edit text it shows the bottom line as pink but not for the first? What's wrong? :-(   @Dhiraj

Comment: check the added screen shot in question . @Dhiraj

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112787/discussion-between-dhiraj-and-user6265109).

Comment: @user6265109  which color you want to give to bottom line??

Comment: accent color i.e pink. @Dhiraj

Comment: I don't want the edit text's bottom line as pink at normal, when we click on edit text it's color changes to pink for both bottom edit text's, but for first it's green at normal also and after selecting also. @Dhiraj

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because Your 1st editText focusing, when your alert layout appear.

add this line in your editText

```
android:focusable="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable focus from your first edittext when the activity is opened, so set 
`android:requestFocus= "false"`

in your xml file. Or try the following

`edittext.clearFocus();`

in your java file.

It will not pick your primary color then.

Hope it works!